# Is it possible to use shell parameter variables ($1, ..., $@) directly in CLI?

Tags: shell, parameter

Sometimes it is necessary to emulate and verify the above variables in small examples and then can be copied immediately to some script, etc.

I tried to solve by using a simple example in the following ways:

```
(find $1) /tmp
sh -c '(find $1) /tmp'
sh -c "find $1" /tmp
echo '(find $1) /tmp' | sh
```

and with other combinations.  Also experimented by adding the shebang interpreter directive `#!/bin/sh -x`, but did not get the desired result.

Can I do this simply?

Comment: `(find $1) /tmp` is a syntax error. Actually `(any-command) more-arguments` is a syntax error. Can you explain differently what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Celada, it's not a syntax error in shells of the `rc` family (`rc`, `es`, `akanga`...), where in that case that's equivalent to `find $1 /tmp`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first argument after `sh -c inline-script` goes to `$0` (which is also used for error messages), and the rest go in `$1`, `$2`...

```
$ sh -c 'blah; echo "$0"; echo "$1"' my-inline-script arg
my-inline-script: blah: command not found
my-inline-script
arg
```

So you want:

```
sh -c 'find "$1"' sh /tmp
```

(in the olden days, you could find `sh` implementations where the first arg went into `$1` instead, so you would do:

```
sh -c 'find "$1"' /tmp /tmp
```

Or:

```
sh -c 'shift "$2"; find "$@"' sh 3 2 /tmp1 /tmp2
```

to account for both behaviours, but those shells are gone now that POSIX is prevalent and publicly available).

---

If you want to set `$1`, `$2` in a local scope within the current shell, that's where you'd use functions. In Bourne-like shells:

```
my_func() {
  find "$1"
}
my_func /tmp
```

Some shells support anonymous functions. That's the case of `zsh`:

```
(){find "$1"} /tmp
```

Or `es`:

```
@{find $1} /tmp
```

---

To change the current positional parameters, permanently, the syntax is shell dependant. [dchirikov has already covered the Bourne-like shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140811/22565) (Bourne, Korn, `bash`, `zsh`, POSIX, `ash`, `yash`...).

The syntax is:

```
set arg1 arg2 ... argn
```

However, you need:

```
set --
```

To empty that list (or `shift "$#"`) and

```
set -- -foo
```

to set `$1` to something starting with `-` or `+`, so it's a good habit to always use `set --` especially when using arbitrary data such as `set -- "$@" other-arg` to add arguments to the end of the positional parameter list.

In shells of the `csh` family (`csh`, `tcsh`), you assign to the `argv` array:

```
set argv=(arg1 arg2)
```

In shells of the `rc` family (`rc`, `es`, `akanga`), to the `*` array:

```
*=(arg1 arg2)
```

Though you can also assign elements individually:

```
2=arg2
```

In `fish`, the positional parameters are in the `argv` array *only* (no `$1`, `$@` there):

```
set argv arg1 arg2
```

In `zsh`, for compatibility with `csh`, you can also assign to the `argv` array:

```
argv=(arg1 arg2)
argv[4]=arg4
```

And you can also do:

```
5=arg5
```

That means you can also do things like:

```
argv+=(another-arg)
```

to add an argument to the end, and:

```
argv[-1]=()
argv[2]=()
```

to remove an argument from the end or the middle, which you can't easily do with other shells.

Answer (score 7):

```
set --
```

is what you need:

```
$ set -- aaa bbb ccc
$ echo "$1"
aaa
$ echo "$2"
bbb
$ echo "$3"
ccc
$ echo "$@"
aaa bbb ccc
```