# Can I create, set permissions, and write to a file with a single Unix command?

Tags: shell

I want to speed up creation of user accounts on some Linux VMs that I am creating, and wondered if I could simplify the process of writing to the new user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` or `~/.ssh/authorized_keys2` file.

My manual process is, approximately (logged in as the new user):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod go-rwx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
echo '... me@machine' >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Is there any way, with a Bash command, a standard GNU command, or any program easily installed on Ubuntu, to condense the `touch`, `chmod`, and `echo` into one command?

Part of the reason I would like to reduce it to one command is so that I can make a shell script that I can run as the initial sudo-capable user on the VM.

Something like:

```
sudo su - me -c 'ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa'
echo '... me@machine' | sudo su - me -c 'xyz 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Where `xyz` is the hypothetical command that creates, sets permissions, and writes the file all in one fell swoop.

Comment: Looks like maybe http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47178/can-files-be-created-with-permissions-set-on-the-command-line can help me.

Comment: You can do `echo '...' >> somefile` without `touch` directly. To avoid using `chmod` set apropriate right for directory via `umask` or `setfacl`

Comment: @Costas, you are right, I can write the file first and then change its permissions. I will probably do that. Changing the directory permission would not reduce the number of commands, but only change the order.

Comment: You change acl only one time but script can be invoked many times.

Comment: Ok. I am less familiar with `umask`. It is a built-in Bash command, right? Is `setfacl` from a different shell? If I want to only set `umask` for specific files, I think I should do it as Stéphane described, in a compound command, yes?

Comment: You can read re access right utilites [here](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/acl). As for `umask` yes, the command sets file mode creation mask just for calling process, so see [Stéphane](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas)'s answer.

Comment: Not 100% related but because I found your question first when searching I'll link to my answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/573371/46158

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note that

```
touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod go-rwx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
echo '... me@machine' >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

offers no benefit over:

```
echo '... me@machine' >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod go-rwx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Permissions are checked upon *opening* a file, not upon reading or writing to it.

So it doesn't matter whether you do the `chmod` before or after adding the content. Someone could still open the file before you do the `chmod` but wait for you to add content before reading it.

Here you want to make sure the file has the right permissions from the start:

```
sudo -Hu user sh -c '
  umask 077 && printf "%s\n" "$1" >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
' sh "$key user@host"
```

`-H` forces `$HOME` to be set to `user`'s home directory (even on systems where `sudo` is configured not to do that by default), so that the `sh` it spawns expands `~` to that directory. You could also use `~user` instead of `~`.

Comment: Good point about the permission checking. I had not thought of that.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the syntax of the third line of your last example. Why is `sh` in the command twice?

Comment: The second `sh` is to give a name (`$0`) to that inline script. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140783) for details

Comment: Slight problem: unlike `sudo su - user`, `sudo -u user` doesn't create a new login shell, so it interprets tilde as the first user's home directory. I found that if I use `sudo su -` then I have to omit the second `sh` in the command.

Comment: @amacleod, then add `-H`.

Answer (score 2):

I use the one-liner below to populate a newly created account with existing keys. It could be easily adapted to append content of existing file.

```
sudo -Hu user /bin/sh -ec 'umask 077; mkdir -p -- ~/.ssh; cat > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' <<EOF
id-rsa AAAA...AA user@example.com
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You might look into [`ssh-copy-id`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id)

Reference:  [3 Steps to Perform SSH Login Without Password Using ssh-keygen & ssh-copy-id](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/)

Comment: These links might be very helpful, but it is also strongly encouraged for answerers to in-line the most helpful bits of information from a given source link.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example this is the best I could do.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -y > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

An important option was the `-y` flag for `ssh-keygen` which allows the public key to be printed to stdout which avoids two steps of creating and reading a file.

To create, set permissions, and write from an existing file you can use the `install` command

```
install -m 0600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The downside to the `install` command is that it does not work with redirection from stdout, meaning you have to copy the contents of an entire file.

Comment: That would suffer from the same gap between file creation and permission change as my original, right? I ended up using `umask` as Stéphane suggested.

Answer (score 0):

actually, `install` can help here

```
install -m 600 /dev/null ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

will replace combnation of `touch` and `chmod`.

And then

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

will add that key to the authorized_keys. Add `sudo` where needed.